# Move an object with delay

Tags: java, swing

I want to move an image turn by turn ( with 40 seconds delay) with swing. can you help me please?
I wrote this code but it's not working. "homer" has the image

```
public void doSomething() {
    frame.add(homer);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 600);
    frame.setTitle("Homer with thread");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    ActionListener ac = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
                homer.setColumn(homer.getColumn() + 3);

        }
    };
    new Timer(40000, ac).start();
}
```

Comment: Remove the `if` check from the `ActionListener` as it will never pass

Comment: why? and how can I correct it?

Comment: Because the `Timer` will trigger the `ActionListener`, in which case the source of the event received by the `ActionListener` is never equal to `KeyEvent.VK_DOWN`

Comment: It's like you haven't done any research yet on this. Please search this site as this type of animation is discussed many times. Use a Swing Timer and Key Bindings.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Key Bindings` and `Swing Timer` to make this functionality.

For example you can do something like this.

```
AbstractAction downAction = new AbstractAction() {


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int delay = 400;// you can inject this property 
            ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener(){
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt2) {
                     //your code here

                  }

            };

                Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
                timer.start();

    }};


 String key = "DOWN";
 KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);
 component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, key);
 component.getActionMap().put(key, downAction);
```